# This cpp code below crashes everytime I input a string of length 4 (the malloc in vector fails)

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am using this program to store the values I input in the nxn matrix.

The first input is number of test cases.
The second is the value of n. So I create a n*n matrix.
Then I input the values for each row Ex: ....
The input is always a combination of '.' or '#'.

Here is a part of the code I am using:

```
#define COL(val, R, C) (R*val)+C ? (R*val)+C:0
int main() {
    // Read the data
    int total_test = 0;
    int tmp, val = 0;
    std::string tmp_s;

    std::cin >> total_test;
    // RUn it total_test number of time
    for (; total_test; total_test--) {
        std::cin >> val;
        matrix path = matrix(val);
        // Parse input
        for (int row = val-1; row >= 0; row--) { //Corrected
            std::cin >> tmp_s;
            std::vector<char> chars(tmp_s.begin(), tmp_s.end());
            for(int col = val-1; col >= 0; col--) {
                if (chars[col] == '#')
                    path.row[row][COL(val, row, col)] = -1; // This is culprit! Thanks @The Dark
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run this program and everytime I give the input string to read as "...." this program crashes. I know the exact line where this occurs..

Its either cin >> tmp_s; (I am pretty sure think this is not the line)
Its this line: std::vector chars(tmp_s.begin(), tmp_s.end());

The GDB has this to say! Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

```
(gdb) s
57              std::cin >> tmp_s;
(gdb) 
....
a.out: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7531cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: UPDATE: I used http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php and compiled it online. The code compiles and runs just file! Whats wrong with my setup? I use GCC 4.9.2 for target x86_64-linux-gnu.

Comment: It would be much easier for your to install Linux on your laptop. Learning to program in C++ thru web site compilation is IMHO weird.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Hahaha... :D Very true. I do use linux ubuntu. I just wanted to try if it compiles on some other setup. It looks like it does work on whatever cpp compiler and setup they have on the site.

Comment: Read about (and be scared of) [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Your program have some.

Comment: _"The code compiles and runs just fine!"_ This is not evidence of anything, particularly when you have crashes on other systems. Almost certainly the online compiler _just happens_ not to crash but that doesn't mean the bug isn't still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have edited out the bit that is going wrong from your posted code.
Looking at your previous code you have a matrix with a `row` element that contains an array with pointers to all the rows, so far so good. You also have a `col` element which has a pointer to all the data (probably should be called `data`).

However, when you are accessing the data you are using this code:

```
path.row[row][COL(val, row, col)] = -1;
```

where `COL`is

```
#define COL(val, R, C) (R*val)+C ? (R*val)+C:0
```

The `COL` macro is used to calculate the position in the data for a row `R` and a column `C`, but your `path.row` pointer has already pre-calculated the position of the row. This means that for any row other than 0, you will be writing to the wrong spot and any row greater than n/2 will be writing past the end of your array, possibly causing a crash like you are seeing.

To fix this, use the array access that you have set up and don't use the `COL` macro (you should remove it from your code):

```
path.row[row][col] = -1;
```

Comment: I am now wondering what is the reason that the error shows up only when I used (multiples of 4) chars as the input. I do understand it is because of the way compiler assigns the memory. But how exactly? Is it possible to somehow know this?

Comment: Memory layout depends on your compiler, so what happens when you go outside the boundaries of an array is "undefined behavior". In this case it is possible that `cin` or `tmp_s` had allocated memory close to where your `col` data was. When you were using multiples of 4, maybe the overrun just managed to hit some critical value, and otherwise it overwrite some part of memory that wasn't so important (e.g. inside the string buffer for string that you had already read past). It is down to luck. As said in the comments, using valgrind might have helped you find this more reliably.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the problem is that you are accessing array out of bounds here:

```
    for (int row = val; row; row--)
```

That is corrupting the stack.
It should be:

```
    for (int row = val-1; row>=0; row--)
```

Other thing is: you should better use `std::getline` instead of `std::cin >> tmp_s` and check the input.

Finally, you don't need to allocate 2 arrays in matrix:
allocate one with size `val*val` and add an `at(int row,int col)` function, that calculates offset as `row*row_size+col`. It will be faster then 2 pointer access.

Comment: Thank you Uldisk. I did correct the array out of bounds. But I still get this error. I will try using getline instead.

Comment: That doesnt help. Tried getline as well. Still fails at that point. Where does the stack get corrupt?

Comment: Show as the changes, and check the cols variable value and tmp_s size after you read the line.

Answer (score 0):

`tmp_s` is empty. Always. But you use it to initialise `chars` then access elements of `chars` that consequently do not exist!

Comment: It is'nt always empty. I provide it input through cin

Comment: @nightfury: No, you don't. There is no code in your question that does that.